# OSRM API provides various results for route, is this server issue?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

We started to try the potential for OSRM

but I have a question related to how is set the server.

Those 2 queries:
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/foot/2.770657539367676,42.48209897188378;2.7791547775268555,42.463359622467586?overview=false&alternatives=false&continue_straight=false&steps=true&geometries=geojson

http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/foot/2.770657539367676,42.48209897188378;2.7791547775268555,42.463359622467586?overview=false&alternatives=false&continue_straight=false&steps=true&geometries=geojson

got the exact same parameters, however answer provided is different

The second one provides the awaited result. Any idea?

Comment: You ask readers to look at the different results returned by 2 copies of the exact same route search. When I click those 2 links, it looks like I get the exact same result from both. If you would like assistance with this, you probably need to provide the results and highlight the differences you see.

Comment: `curl -s <URL> | md5sum` always returns the same hash after multiple executions. The results are identical.

If you experience different results then one potential reason could be a load balancing mechanism with multiple servers. In this case it is possible that the map data of these servers is from different dates. However, this is just a wild guess.